# Adding Data to Access using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I'm a .NET Newbie... and I'm trying to rewrite a program I wrote in VB6. The problem is that I have 41 values to use to create a new records in Access. Almost everything I've read uses `INSERT INTO` (but 41 fields makes a LONG SQL statement).

**NOTES:**

The Source and Target Data exists in Access.

I created a Structure call `TargetXStudentRec` that holds all of the fields that I'm populating.

The Fields names in the Access DB `Student ID`, `Last Name` are import field names for the system the data is going into.

**IN visual basic 6 I used**

```
TargetXStudentRec.AddNew
TargetXStudentRec("Student ID") = .Student_ID
TargetXStudentRec("Last Name") = .LastName
TargetXStudentRec("First Name") = .FirstName
..........................
TargetXStudentRec.Update
```

Is there a way to do this in ADO.net?
Or what is the best solution?

Comment: I would suggest using OLEDB and employ parameters for supplying insert values.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this example is useful to you: http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/UseOleDbDataAdaptertoinsertarowintoAccessdatabase.htm
You may define Data Adapters and Rows to make your insert easier.